# How do you modify a EF-Core Database-First (PostgreSQL) project to also work with SQLite and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

## My scenario

I have a PostgreSQL database. I've created models (the `Scaffold-Db` command) for it using the `EntityFrameworkCore` "database first" approach. The EntityFrameworkCore classes are in a .NET Standard 2.0 class library, because I'm planning on using it on multiple platforms (`WPF`, Xamarin.Forms).

PostgreSQL works with my WPF project. In order to get it working with my Xamarin.Forms project, I've created a migration for SQLite using the command `Add-Migration`.

Then I tried to run the `Update-Database` command, which failed and told me that I couldn't have sequences in the SQLite database. So I opened the migration file and deleted all the lines that were adding sequences. And then, the `Update-Database` command worked just fine.

## The problem

The problem is, when I run the Xamarin.Forms project and try to use the database, I get an exception saying "**SQLite does not support sequences**".

## The Question

Does anyone have any experience with **manually editing a migration so it would work with SQLite**?

#### Here's what I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3.5
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.4
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 2.2.4
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.2.4
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2.4
- Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.709249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I think I've figured it out.
I forgot to delete this part `modelBuilder.HasSequence("some_sequence_id");` in my `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method.

Now the database works on both `WPF` and `Xamarin.Forms`, the only thing left to do is a deciding mechanism for the `DbContext` so it would use the correct provider depending on the platform.

I hope this helps someone.